# What are the behaviors of typical web browser address bars?

Tags: browser, address-bar

I need a list of web browser address bar behaviors, as part of a research experiment.
For example:

1) The most basic behavior is to type a full web address, e.g. `http://www.abc.com` and press ENTER to navigate to the web site.

2) Typing just a domain name (e.g. `abc`) and pressing CTRL+ENTER (on Windows) automatically prepends the `http://` and appends the `.com` and navigates to the web site.

3) In some cases typing `abc.com` and pressing ENTER navigates to `http://www.abc.com` - what is the precise heuristic here?

... etc.

Comment: So you want us to do the research for you?

Comment: What do you consider typical? Internet Explorer? Some things such as navigating to typing abc.com but navigating to somewhere else don't have anything to do with the address bar (like whether the site requires https or not).

Comment: Sime - oh please, come off it. Obviously I'm not simply trying to compile these behaviors - that is hardly novel work :)

Comment: @bright AFAIK No browser will prepend "www." to a URL. That's always something the specific server handles by redirecting.

Comment: Ocelot - well, there is at least some address bar behavior there - adding the http://, at a minimum. The www. is possibly a redirect - but it would be interesting to know if any browsers actually add it themselves for performance or other reasons. Edit: @meagar indicates the latter does not occur.

Comment: @bright Usually, when presenting a question on SO, you want to show that you have done some initial research yourself. btw you have to prepend "@" if you want the person (that you're replying to) to get notified.

Comment: Download a few browsers and find out for yourself... They're all free.

Answer (score 1):

As for 3), I do think that it's a redirect, which is being done on the server-side (that is, the server notices you are trying to access the domain directly and redirects to www.*), so no browser-specific behavior here.

And Google Chrome for example treats everything that does not have a valid top-level domain suffix or protocol prefix (such as http://) as a search query, which, on pressing Enter, leads you to Google.com?q={query}

Comment: I think some browers do prepend www. and try again if the original request returned 404.